# Understanding configuration of NTP server

Tags: ntp

I opened /etc/ntp.conf file. I have the following entries:

```
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
restrict  0.centos.pool.ntp.org mask 255.255.255.255
```

I am not sure what `mask 255.255.255.255` is doing exactly? I read some posts ([post](https://serverfault.com/questions/655039/how-to-have-ntpd-serve-only-my-local-subnet)) around but still not sure what it means?

Comment: Really just two lines? The rest of the file is relevant too

Comment: @roaima. It has 2 more servers and 2 more same restricts but with different IPs.

Comment: That would have impacted my answer. I see you've got something you're happy with, but next time please include the context as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `server` option defines a remote NTP server with which your local NTP server will establish a connection.

The `restrict` option controls how other hosts can interact with your local NTP daemon. It effects both hosts to which your server initiates connections, via the `server` option, and also hosts which attempt to initiate connections with your server.

The basic syntax of the command is:

```
restrict address [mask mask] [ippeerlimit int] [flag ...]
```

The `flag` argument is used to limit the ways in which a remote host can interact with your local server; an entry with no `flag` setting means the named host(s) have full access.

To understand the `mask` setting, it helps to read the `Access control commands` of the [`ntpd.conf` man page](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/ntp.conf/):

> The *address* argument expressed in dotted-quad form is the address
> of a host or network.  Alternatively, the *address* argument can be
> a valid host DNS name.  The *mask* argument expressed in dotted-quad form
> defaults to `255.255.255.255`, meaning that the
> address is treated as the address of an individual host.  A
> default entry (address `0.0.0.0`, mask `0.0.0.0`) is always included
> and is always the first entry in the list.  Note that text string
> `default`, with no mask option, may be used to indicate the default
> entry.

And earlier in the same document:

> A match occurs when the bitwise AND of the mask and the packet source address
> is equal to the bitwise AND of the mask and address in the list.

So if you have:

```
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0
```

Then the "bitwise AND of the mask and the packet source" for anything in the `192.168.1.0/24`  network will be `192.168.1.0`, so all hosts in that network will match. On the other hand, if you have:

```
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.252
```

Then only hosts `192.168.1.0` through `192.168.1.3` will match.

When applied to a hostname, as you show in your example, the name is first converted to an address and then the mask is applied. I would argue that in most cases it doesn't make sense to use a mask other than `255.255.255.255` when using a hostname, and since that's the default mask you could write instead:

```
restrict 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
```

The configuration you have means "connect to `0.centos.pool.ntp.org` and allow it to be used as a source of time synchronization".

---

Regarding your comments:

> What do you mean by "Then only hosts 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.3 will match." please? You mean they will connect with each other. In other words, my NTP server will try to reach all hosts in range 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.3 for time query?

No. The `restrict` option does not control to which hosts your local NTP server will attempt to connect; this is what the `server` option is for. The `restrict` option controls what information your NTP server is willing to exchange once a connection is established -- either by your server initiating a connection to a remote server, or by a remote server initiating a connection to your server.

> Also second question please, so mask 255.255.255.255 will allow only one host, which is 0.centos.pool.ntp.org to connect to my NTP daemon? If yes why is that given that if we apply AND between IP address of 0.centos.pool.ntp.org (I understand we have to convert to to numerical IP) and 255.255.255.255 it will give us 0.centos.pool.ntp.org?

I'm not sure I follow this question. If you `and` an address with `255.255.255.255`, you get the original address. That means that only the specific address given as the first argument to `restrict` will match.

As I said in the earlier part of my answer, I don't think it makes much sense to make use of the `mask` parameter when specifying a host by name, since you will typically always want the default behavior (only match what is specified explicitly).

Comment: What do you mean by "Then only hosts 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.3 will match." please? You mean they will connect with each other. In other words, my NTP server will try to reach all hosts in range 192.168.1.0 through 192.168.1.3 for time query?

Comment: Also second question please, so mask `255.255.255.255` will allow only one host, which is `0.centos.pool.ntp.org` to connect to my NTP daemon? If yes why is that given that if we apply AND between IP address of `0.centos.pool.ntp.org` (I understand we have to convert to to numerical IP) and `255.255.255.255` it will give us `0.centos.pool.ntp.org`?

Comment: I've added some answers to your comments.